# How to get string representation of dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have some javascript code that creates a table row by generating a string and appending it to the table. Something like this:

```
var str = '<tr><td>Column</td><!--More columns--></tr>';
$('#my-table').append(str);
```

There is one element (an input) in the row that has a LOT of attributes. This is hard to read as a long string so I want to create this one particular element a different way - using `$()` and passing in attributes as an object as documented [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) - and then concatenating it with the string above. So I tried to do something like this:

```js
var el = $('<input>', {
 type: 'text',
 name: 'some_name'
});

var str = '<tr><td>test</td><td>'+el.html()+'</td></tr>';
$('#my-table').append(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">

</table>
```

This should (I thought) create a textbox as the second column in the table but it doesn't work. I just get a empty cell and no errors. What am I doing wrong? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery html() is the innerHTML not the outerHTML.  You want the latter.

```js
var el = $('<input>', { type: 'text', name: 'some_name' });
var str = '<tr><td>test</td><td>'+ el[0].outerHTML +'</td></tr>';
$('#my-table').append(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table"></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var $input = $('<input>', {
    type: 'text',
    name: 'some_name',
    /* ... more attributes ... */
});
var $tr = $("<tr>").appendTo('#my-table');
var $td = $("<td>").append($input).appendTo($tr);

// possibly do other things with $input, $tr, and $td
```

That being said, you really should not build complex HTML with jQuery. It's cumbersome, leads to unreadable and ultimately buggy, hard-to-maintain code. (Even more than that, you really should not build HTML by concatenating strings.)

Build a data structure (an array of objects) and then let an HTML templating library do the work. There are quite a few mature libraries to choose from, handlebars.js being a prominent one. It will pay in the form of *much* cleaner Javascript code to use one of them.

Comment: Hier is a template engine like "java standard tag Library" [link](https://twilighttitus.github.io/jquery.plugins)

Comment: Please don't promote your early alpha libraries on StackOverflow. It's not even documented yet.

Comment: It's documented and it's not alpha! Open the link, read the site and you are able to find the doc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I completely agree with you that I should use a templating library. I will probably do something like that. The other answer helped me understand why my code didn't work like I thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

you want the Value from input, not the inner html. Try this:

```
var str = '<tr><td>test</td><td>'+el.val()+'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: But I do want the inner html. The problem is that the output is empty.